# How can I make an https request using django 1.6 test client?

Tags: python, django, testing, https

I know that I can do this with

```
self.client.get('/path/', {'query': 'abs'}, secure=True)
```

In recent versions, but it does not work in django 1.6, as argument 'secure' was added in 1.7. How would I be able to achieve this in the 1.6 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a trick http://codeinthehole.com/writing/testing-https-handling-in-django/ hope that helps